# How to return list of different Classes sharing the same parent in Java?

Tags: java

I am looking for a small help with my piece of code trying to return list of classes which share the same parent abstract class / interface. Here is the code snippet:

```
public <T extends Animal> List<Class<T>> getAnimalTypes() {
    return Arrays.<T>asList(Dog.class, Cat.class, Bear.class);
}
```

`Dog`, `Cat` and `Bear` are classes that extends abstract class `Animal`. What am I missing ? Thanks, Ondrej,

Comment: you are trying to return intances of Class, not of those classes

Comment: `T` is _something_ concrete, not _anything_ concrete. What you're looking for seems to be closer to this one: `public static List<Class<? extends Animal>> getAnimalTypes() { return Arrays.asList(Dog.class, Cat.class, Bear.class); }`

Comment: Instead of adding .class arguments to the asList(...), try creating instance of these classes and then add those instances to asList(...). It should work. You dont want to return a list of classes, but instances of those classes, right ?

Comment: @vivek I want to return list of classes, not list of instances

Comment: @fluffy, this does the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define a method that returns a list of `Class` objects with the same parent abstract class/interface, specify the return type `List<Class<? extends Animal>>` to that method:

```
 public List<Class<? extends Animal>> getAnimalTypes() {
   return Arrays.asList(Dog.class, Cat.class, Bear.class);
 }
```

That says to the compiler to require a type of class that extends the class `Animal`. There is no need to specify the generic type `T`.